# How to manage Firebase Auth users from Vue js?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication

I have an application in Vue JS, and as a back end I have firebase, both for the Auth (email and password) and for the database (cloud firestore)

The problem is that I do not know how to do a user administration for an administrator user, where he can create or disable users (I am not interested in modifying information or checking emails, I am interested in creating users and deleting or disabling them from An option within my app.

The problem is that I can't find a way to do it from a Front End, I only see things with back ends in node, Java and go, but since I don't have a back as such that I have done (I already indicated that I only use firebase as back and Vue as front) I don't know how to make this page.

If you could help me or give me an idea / guide on how to do it, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Your question is very broad for Stack Overflow... You may be interested by this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-an-admin-module-for-managing-users-access-and-roles-34a94cf31a6e) which explains how to create an Admin module for managing users access and roles (disclaimer, I'm the author). The article does not explain how to delete a user but you can use the `deleteUser` method of the Admin SDK (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth#deleteuser)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google Cloud Functions to handle the backend as admin-auth is not directly possible on the frontend.
When an JWT auth token is return check if the user is an admin with custom claims. you can create a separate list and add emails of the admins there in your RTDB or Firestore and then redirect to the admin page.